# Why did Ishullanu refuse to make love to Ishtar?

Tags: gilgamesh

When Ishtar proposes to Gilgamesh, he articulates the stories of her previous lovers who suffered badly as a consequence of being with her. However, there is one of them who is named Ishullanu that when Ishtar asks to be with her he strongly refuses. What kind of a man and for what possible reason would reject a goddess like Ishtar? Could it be the same reason as Gilgamesh's or is there a background reason for it since it is not explicit in the epic? Or since Ishullanu also mentioned that he did not want to be subject to slander and insults could he be married to someone else?

The following lines are my reference,

> "0 my Ishullanu, let us taste your vigour:
>
> Put out your 'hand' and stroke my quim!"
>
> But Ishullanu said to you:
>
> '''Me! What do you want of me?
>
> Did my mother not bake? Have I not eaten,
>
> that now I should eat the bread of slander and insults?
>
> Should I let only rushes cover me in winter?"

Comment: Epic of Gilgamesh seems to be having darken Ishtar as it's target. So, it's obviously done to show Ishtar as goddess, that people do not want connect (which can't be true really since she had many worshippers and it seems that Epic of Gilgamesh hadn't change it much).